# Como checar credenciais antes de fazer autenticação no Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, login, autenticação, laravel-5.3

A minha aplicação utiliza a autenticação pronta do Laravel, porém estou precisando que os usuários façam login a a partir de um webservice.

Então o que estou tentando fazer é que se o cara existir no banco da aplicação, ele faz autenticação nativa do Laravel mesmo, se não, ai eu utilizo o webservice.

O problema é que antes de autenticar, eu preciso checar se ele existe no banco e gostaria de saber se tem algum método nativo do Laravel que eu possa fazer isso (sem ser consulta com `DB::select()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `attempt` do componente de `Auth` para isso.

Com esse método ele já vai efetuar a autenticação para você, sem precisar redirecionar novamente para o método nativo.

```
public function authenticate($email, $password)
{
    // No lugar do helper você pode usar a Facade também

    if (auth()->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }

    // Loga pelo webservice
}
```

[Mais detalhes na documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users).

Comment: Funcionou, até tinha olhado esse metodo na documentação, mas não tinha entendido direito como ele funciona. Obrigado.